# Laravel whereHas ManyToMany relation but then order by a value in the third table

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables

```
entry (
id,
title,
other_stuff)

entry_award (
id,
award_id,
entry_id)

award (
id,
name,
type)
```

I am trying to create a laravel query which lets me get all the entries that have awards, and order them by award.type ASC

```
$Entries = Entry::with('award')
    ->whereHas('award', function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('award.award_id','ASC');
    })->paginate(20);
```

But this doesn't work.

This is the sql version of it

```
SELECT DISTINCT entry.*
FROM entry, award, entry_award
WHERE entry.id = entry_award.entry_id
AND award.id = entry_award.award_id
ORDER BY award.type ASC;
```

Now I tried to just use the raw sql for it, but the problem seems to be that laravel does not then recognize the result as Entry models/objects. And i need to get other Entry relations later on in the html via blade.

So how can I either make a query-builder query that gets me all entries that have awards and orders them by award.type value

or use the raw sql but have Laravel see it as an array of Entry 
objects instead of just an array of JSON values.

```
class Entry extends Model {

    public function entry_award(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Award', 'entry_award');
    }
}

class Award extends Model {

    public function entries() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entry', 'entry_award');
    }
}
```